# Flink adding rebalance to stream cause to job failure when StreamExecutionEnvironment set using TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to run streaming job that consumes messages from Kafka transforms them and sinks to the Cassandra.

Current code snippet is failing

```
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = getExecutionEnv("dev")
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime)
.
.
.
.

  val source = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)
              .uid("kafkaSource")
              .rebalance

    val transformedObjects = source.process(new EnrichEventWithIngestionTimestamp)
        .setParallelism(dataSinkParallelism)
    sinker.apply(transformedObjects,dataSinkParallelism)


  class EnrichEventWithIngestionTimestamp extends ProcessFunction[RawData, TransforemedObjects] {
    override def processElement(rawData: RawData,
                                context: ProcessFunction[RawData, TransforemedObjects]#Context,
                                collector: Collector[TransforemedObjects]): Unit = {
     val currentTimestamp=context.timerService().currentProcessingTime()
      context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(currentTimestamp)
      collector.collect(TransforemedObjects.fromRawData(rawData,currentTimestamp))
    }
}
```

but if `rebalance` is commented out, or the job is changed to use TimeCharacteristic.EventTime and watermark assignment, as in fallowing snippet, then it works.

```
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = getExecutionEnv("dev")
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
.
.

  val source = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)
              .uid("kafkaSource")
              .rebalance
              .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessRawDataTimestampExtractor[RawData](Time.seconds(1)))


val transformedObjects = source.map(rawData=>TransforemedObjects.fromRawData(rawData))
        .setParallelism(dataSinkParallelism)
    sinker.apply(transformedObjects,dataSinkParallelism)
```

The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: 1
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.checkThrowSourceExecutionException(SourceStreamTask.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.processInput(SourceStreamTask.java:133)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.run(StreamTask.java:301)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:406)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 1
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:45)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.collector.selector.DirectedOutput.collect(DirectedOutput.java:143)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.collector.selector.DirectedOutput.collect(DirectedOutput.java:45)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:727)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$AutomaticWatermarkContext.processAndCollect(StreamSourceContexts.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$AutomaticWatermarkContext.processAndCollectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:194)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:409)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka010Fetcher.emitRecord(Kafka010Fetcher.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.runFetchLoop(Kafka09Fetcher.java:156)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:715)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:203)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.getBufferBuilder(RecordWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.copyFromSerializerToTargetChannel(RecordWriter.java:169)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.emit(RecordWriter.java:154)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.emit(RecordWriter.java:120)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:107)
    ... 16 more
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Or there Is a limitation of using `rebalance` function when TimeCharacteristic set to IngestionTime?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the flink version that you are using?

Seems your issue is related to this Jira ticket

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14087

Did u only use `rebalance` once in your task? The `recordWriter` may share same `channelSelector` which decides where the record will be forwarded to. Your stack trace shows it is trying to select an out-of-bound channel.

Comment: thanks for quick reply .
I am using Flink **1.9.1** and doing rebalance only once after consuming data from kafka.

Comment: I tried with the same flink version, it works for me. Which kafka consumer are you using? What is the parallelism for your job?

Comment: Kafka **0.10.2.1**, parallelism = **5**